# Fail to boot after installing amdgpu-pro driver

Tags: drivers, gnome

I installed amdgpu driver and after that whenever I boot The message:
started gnome display manager dispatcher service system changes.pp link was shut down
and then it stucks

I entered recovery mode and uninstalled the graphics driver but the problem still occurs.
I managed to enter graphics mode by entering recovery mode then resumed boot from there.

I also tried reinstalling gdm, gnome-shell but no luck.

Any idea what still causing the problem?
Thanks.

If that helps vlc craches when I open a video but trying:  vlc -V x11

it works showing:
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, which release? How did you install `amdgpu` driver. There is no need to install it on modern Ubuntu releases.

Comment: I use ubuntu 18.04. I installed it like here: [link](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635) It seems it's for 16.04 I didn't notice.
But I uninstalled it and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed updates *I didn't want to do this because of the quota limit* and it finally solved the problem.

It seems one of the packages that I still don't know which was broken and the update replaced it.